# Null object pattern in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, oop, null

In Java, it is very easy to code the following design:

```
public abstract class Pizza {
    public static final Pizza.NULL = new Pizza() {
        /* "null" implementations */
    }

    /* actual/abstract implmentations */
}
```

What is the preferred method to attain the same efficient scenario in Objective-C? I have been unable to find any documentation on the subject, and I have tried a couple different scenarios with `static const`, `#define` etc. but none of them seem to work out as well as the Java method above.

I would like to avoid writing a concrete NullPizza class that has a static method to obtain the singleton instance, as it seems more 'proper' for it to be some final property/field of the highest-level interface. (Pizza, in this case.)

**Edit:** While I understand how the NULL pattern specifically would be handled due to Obj-C's unique method of handling method calls to 'nil', what about other static common instances, such as Response.YES and Response.NO? (See comments for discussion.)

Comment: Can not compile this code on Java.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Response.YES and Response.NO, I assume you have instances that you do want to change, rather than just making all Response properties read-only.

A common pattern in Cocoa is to have both immutable and mutable versions of a class (NSArray versus NSMutableArray).  For your response example, it would make sense to have an immutable Response class that has the static YES and NO methods, and a MutableResponse subclass that exposes setters for those times where you do want objects to change them.  Does this cover your second example?

Answer (score 12):

There is no need for this type of pattern in Objective-C because it is not considered a runtime error to message a nil instance of a class. If the method has a defined return type, there are defined returns from messaging a nil object (e.g., methods that return an integer return 0 when messaging a nil object).

Comment: That's true, I was simply using the NOP as an example. What would you do in a situation where there are two default implementations of a class, say Response, and you wanted a Response.YES and a Response.NO that were static, final implementations?

Comment: just create factory methods which return those instances, as +[NSDecimalNumber zero] and +[NSDecimalNumber one] do. BTW there's no 'final' in ObjC.

Comment: That was my initial plan, but how do you ensure that the instance returned is not modified? The instance should be a singleton, so you aren't wasting memory returning a new instance every time, but if every call to [Pizza null] returns the same reference, couldn't that object be altered?

Comment: In ObjC, how were you planning to actually use whatever object [Pizza null] might return? Really, the point is that there is no actual need for a null pizza instance like there is in Java.

Comment: Again though, take the Response example. If [Response yes] returns a particular singleton instance, how can I ensure (since this instance is shared throughout the app) that none of its properties will be changed? Will I have to write a ResponseNo class and override the setters? This seems tedious.

Comment: You can make all the properties of the Response object read only and set the yes/no attribute in the init method. That way your singleton instance cannot be modified and neither can its child attributes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things which can help here. The first is `nil`, the Objective-C equivalent of the Java NULL pointer - it can actually receive messages and respond to them. It will always return `nil` if the return value is an object, and `0` if the return value is some primitive type. Therefore if the Null behaviour of your object is "do nothing" you can easily just use `nil` as the Null value.

The other thing which is helpful is for when you need to store a placeholder or null value in a container object - these usually throw exceptions if you attempt to add `nil` as a value. Instead you can use the singleton `+[NSNull null]`, which does nothing except act as a "this space intentionally left blank" object.

With these two weapons at your disposal there should be no reason to write a null instance of a custom class :-)

Comment: see my comment in reply to your comment :-) and now let's leave the meta-thread... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to provide this implementation. You're asking for something that is a language feature of Java to be implemented in Objective-C - you can do it but you have to write the code that is in the Java runtime yourself - there is nothing to stop you doing this but it's not something the language has built in.

It's a bit like asking "How do I show a Windows style 'one menu per window" UI in Cocoa' - you can do it but it's not provided for free from the framework. Or, "how can I easily implement Objective-C's nil pointer handling in Java?"

If you really want to see this type of functionality I think you should follow the NSArray/NSMutableArray design pattern. Declare a superclass that can handle all of your special cases:

```
@interface NullPizza : NSObject
{
}
- (BOOL)areYouANullPizza;
@end
```

and then subclass with your real Pizza and include a newNullPizza class method (which is just syntax sugar):

```
@interface Pizza : NullPizza
{
}

+ (Pizza*)Null;
@end

@implementation Pizza
+ (Pizza*)newNullPizza
{
    return [[NullPizza]alloc init]; // Singleton code left as an exercise.
}

- (BOOL)areYouANullPizza;
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Note that if you wanted to implement a `+(Pizza*)NULL` method on Pizza you should autorelease the new NullPizza you create.

Disclaimer, I typed this code straight into SO. I'd be surprised if it compiles but you get the idea.